# oracle compare date to null

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a query where i am comparing a date from one table to a max date from another table. The problem i am having is when the date is null that is being compared against. So take the following query:

```
select col1 from table1 where date > (select max(date) from table b);
```

The query works fine except for when the subquery returns 0 rows. In the case of 0 rows i want it to return all rows. So in other words i want the date to compare to a datetime min value. So for in the case of 0 rows i want to compare:

```
date > '01-01-1900'
```

I have tried using case statements with no luck but i feel like i am missing something simple.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want to use a NVL function to assist.

```
(NVL(p_datefield, to_date('01/01/1901','MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

so for you:

```
select col1 from table1 where date > (select max(NVL(date, to_date('01/01/1901','MM/DD/YYYY')) from table b);
```

the idea is 01/01/1901 represents `null`.  If you don't like it, then change that date to something you can come to grips on to represent `null` on your behalf.

UPDATE #1..a comment from below suggests that COALESCE would work better.  It could...so here's that example:

```
select col1 from table1 where date > (select coalesce(date, to_date('01/01/1901','MM/DD/YYYY')) from table b);
```

Now you have a choice.
Enjoy.

Comment: `coalesce` is better than `nvl`

Comment: So i updated description for the case when query returns 0 rows to have it return all rows due to fact of comparing to min date. Is this possible?

Comment: So that is why i was thinking case statement to return min date for case of 0 rows

Comment: fyi `coalesce` is (in this case) just the better option for portability if you might ever switch DBMS as `coalesce` is in the SQL-92 standard and `nvl` is exclusive to Oracle

Comment: Your original answer contains a call to `max`, but your UPDATE #1 answer doesn't.  Did you intend to write `...select max(coalesce(date, ...`?

Comment: @jason44107 he's saying we can use this. 
```select col1 from table1 where date > (select coalesce(max(date), to_date('01/01/1901','MM/DD/YYYY')) from table b);```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to happen when the subquery returns no rows?  A comparison of a date against null will result in nothing being returned by the main query - which is technically the correct response.  If you don't want that then you would need to substitute a string value for the null using the [NVL function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it would be like this:

```sql
select NVL(max(date, to_date('01/01/1901','MM/DD/YYYY')) from table b
```

Since:
you want the max value from the table and then check on null value – not the other way around.

Comment: [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)